# Как лучше реализовать единый сервис авторизации для разных сайтов на ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, token, аутентификация

Есть разные web приложения реализованные на разных фреймворках, основная часть реализована с помощью ASP.NET Core. Задача следующая, нужно загнать их все (или хотя бы те что на ASP.NET Core) в единую систему авторизации, другими словами один раз введенный пароль и логин дает доступ ко всем сервисам к которым данному пользователю предоставлен доступ. Каким образом лучше это реализовать?

Comment: Почитайте по SSO. Реализаций много лучше хуже у всех свои недостатки и достоинства.

Comment: Еще OpenID есть. Можно еще использовать сервис авторизации соцсетей или Яндекса/Гугла.